# Ask for student's current CGPA and target CGPA, and then calculate minimum grade to achieve target CGPA

Tags: java, loops

cre is currently accumulated credits, multiply by 12 because current credit hours is 12.

req is my equation of minimum credits to hit target CGPA.

```
cre = data[0][0]*12;
req = (26*data[0][1])-cre;
```

For next semester, 4 subjects are taken, and the credits hour for each subject is 4,4,3,3.Total up = 14. So I come out with this, what am I trying to do is create a loop and increment x by 0.01 until the total credits of subs meet the req:

```
if(((56+cre)/26)>data[0][1]) {
        do {

             double x = i/100;

             sub1 = 4*x;
             sub2 = 4*x;
             sub3 = 3*x;
             sub4 = 3*x;

            total = sub1 + sub2 + sub3 + sub4;

                i++;



        } while (total<req);

        System.out.println(sub1/4.0);
        System.out.println(sub2/4.0);
        System.out.println(sub3/3.0);
        System.out.println(sub4/3.0);
        }
```

Lastly, I try to divide all subs by 4 and 3 to find minimum gpa required for each subjects to hit the target CGPA.

Comment: I don't think my code is correct, cause I am having all equal output. For eg, 3.5 3.5 3.5 3.5. It is supposed to be 3.5 3.5 3.0 2.0, something like this

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly so that the problem is well-described, but in the shortes possible manner.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, we can only guess. Most likely this is the issue:

```
double x = i/100;
```

If `i` is an integer, then this will equal zero for every `i` less than 100. You probably want floating point division.

```
double x = i/100.0;
```

---

You could find a simpler solution with a little math. First, the equation for calculating GPA is

```
sum(grade_points_for_all_classes) / total_hours = GPA
```

The "grade point" for any class is

```
grade * credit_hours
```

Now, we want to calc the min grade (`min_grade`) for all the new classes to reach a new `desired_gpa`. The equation would be

```
(sum(grade_points_for_prev_classes) + (min_grade * sum(new_class_hours)) / total_hours = desired_gpa
```

Where `total_hours` is the total number of credit hours (new and old classes). Solving for `min_grade` we get:

```
min_grade = (desired_gpa * total_hours - sum(grade_points_for_prev_classes)) / sum(new_class_hours)
```

Example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    double goalGPA = 3.25;

    // Create an array of previous courses
    double [][] prevCourses = {
        {4, 4.0},
        {4, 3.0},
        {3, 2.0},
        {2, 1.0}
    };

    // Calc grade points for prev courses
    // and also total credit hours for prev courses
    double gradePointsPrevCourses = 0;
    int totalCreditHours = 0;
    for (double [] c : prevCourses) {
        gradePointsPrevCourses += c[0] * c[1];
        totalCreditHours += c[0];
    }

    // Create an array of the new courses
    // Not concerned with grades yet so fill with zero
    double [][] newCourses = {
        {4, 0.0},
        {4, 0.0},
        {3, 0.0},
        {3, 0.0}
    };

    // Calc new credit hours
    // and add to prev credit hours
    int newCreditHours = 0;
    for (double [] c : newCourses) {
        newCreditHours += c[0];
    }
    totalCreditHours += newCreditHours;

    // Solve
    double minGrade = (goalGPA * totalCreditHours - gradePointsPrevCourses) / newCreditHours;
    if (minGrade <= 4.0) {
        System.out.println(String.format("You will need a %.2f in all classes to get a %.2f GPA", minGrade, goalGPA));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(String.format("Sorry, a %.2f is unobtainable.", goalGPA));
    }
}
```